# BMW 320i / e36 / M50 overheating

Tags: overheating

I have changed my thermostat, waterpump and radiator cap. radiator was bleed. No oil in the water and no oil in the water but car still overheat

Comment: Can you explain a little more. What happens? Is this when highway driving or round town? How fast does it overheat etc.

Comment: Welcome to the site. So you changed all of this because it was overheating? Is the cooling fan(s) working? Does it overheat only when the AC is on, all the time, only when sitting? What was the condition of the old coolant? Condition of the passages and inside of the water pump? Did you have the radiator flow checked? If it was very dirty, there may be a blockage.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that the overheating issue relates to the themostatic coupling which your radiator fan is attached to.  This is effectively a thermal clutch which allows the fan to turn freely when cold but when it gets warm it is supposed to lock the fan firmly to the pulley wheel to which it is attached.

When these couplings fail, the fan clutch effectively "slips" so the fan fails to generate sufficient airflow across the radiator.  Thankfully replacement is a fairly simple operation and the fan clutch is not an expensive part.

You may find that [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vi_TKW76tpc) video provides more information.

With regards to the starting issue, I suspect it probably relates to corroded wiring terminals or a corroded / poor earthing strap.

Answer (score 0):

Low battery/a bad fan motor could be the issue, so long as the coolant system is bled and you know the radiator is not clogged, other things such as a bad temp sensor or a bad thermostat could be the issues as well

Comment: The BMW E36 does not use a fan motor, the engine is mounted longitudinally with the fan driven directly by the engine (via a thermostatic fan clutch).